# symfony language select based on subdomain

Tags: php, internationalization, symfony1

My symfony app should get user's language from subdomain:

en.project.com - for english
fr.project.com - for french

and so on...
Special filter get 'GET' param 'lang' from current uri and save it in user attribute.
How can I setup apache virtual host config for multiple subdomains?

Comment: My coffee should be hot, but instead it's lukewarm..

Answer (score 2):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName blah.com
ServerAlias de.blah.com en.blah.com fr.blah.com
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Read more about server aliases: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#serveralias

Your Symfony filter can simply parse the domain during the first request and set a session variable.
This is untested but should work:

```
<?php class localeFilter extends sfFilter
{
  public function execute($filterChain)
  {
    // Execute this filter only once
    if ($this->isFirstCall()) {
      $host = $_REQUEST['HTTP_HOST'];
      $locale = array_shift(explode(".",$host));
      $this->getUser()->setAttribute('locale', $locale);
    }

    // Execute next filter
    $filterChain->execute();
  }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need simply to rewrite wildcard domain using mod_rewrite, and when you'll have subdomain as a parameter, you can go ahead.

http://www.easymodrewrite.com/example-subdomains

Answer (score 0):

Try to add them as `ServerAlias` in your httpd config file.